# How to add a specific domain validator in a flutter form?

Tags: flutter

I have a login page but I only want the form to accept emails with a specific domain (e.g. @abc.net). Here is the code I have so far. How would I implement this?

```
Widget _showEmailInput() {
    return new Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(15.0, 15.0, 15.0, 0.0),
        child: TextFormField(
          maxLines: 1,
          keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
          autofocus: false,
          decoration: new InputDecoration(
              hintText: 'Enter Email', icon: Icon(Icons.email, color: black)),
          validator: (value) => value.isEmpty ? 'Email can not be empty' : null,
          onSaved: (value) => _email = value.trim(),
        ));
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Method 1**

```
var isValid = value.toLowerCase().endsWith('your_domain.com');
```

**Method 2 (RegEx)**

```
validator: (value) {
  if (value.isEmpty) return 'Email can not be empty'

  var rx = RegExp("\b*@abc\.net\$",caseSensitive: false);
  return rx.hasMatch(value) ? null : 'Invalid domain name';
}
```

Just replace **abc.net** to your desired domain name

```
print(rx.hasMatch('sdfsdf@sdf.net')); // false
print(rx.hasMatch('sdfsdf@abc.net')); // true
print(rx.hasMatch('sdfsdf@ABC.org')); // false
print(rx.hasMatch('sdfsdf@ABc.net')); // true
```